# whether the injective immersion is embedding if two topologies are equal?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $f:M^m \rightarrow N^n$ be a injective immersion between two manifold $M$ and $N$. There are two ways to idenify the topology(furthmore the differential structure) of $f(M)$.

One is set the topology induced by $f$. It is of the form $\{(f(U), \varphi\circ f^{-1})\}$. Where $\{(U, \varphi)\}$ is the differential form of $M$.

The other is sub-topology of $N$ which is of the form $\{(V \cap f(M), \psi)\}$. Where $\{(V, \psi)\}$ is the differential of $N$.

When $f$ is embedding, it is clear that homeomorphism implies that above two topology are equal.

My confusion is the converse proposition. That is, Suppose $f$ is injective immersion and above two topology are equal, whether $f$ is a embedding or not?

If it is, Please show me the reason.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: By immersion, do you mean $f$ is smooth and $df$ is injective at every point?

Comment: Think about this: when $f$ is an embedding $f(M)$ is a submanifold. This is precisely the condition that the second set gives a smooth structure on the image. So can you have an immersion who's image is a submanifold but $f$ isnt an embedding?

Comment: What does "Where $\{(U, \varphi)\}$ is the **differential form** of $M$" mean? It seems that $\{(U, \varphi)\}$ should denote the **differentiable structure** of $M$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman. In manifold terminology, immersion means that the rank$f = m = $dim($M$).

Comment: @PaulFrost, sorry, i were confused with them.

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman, The definition mentioned by my book, It can be seen that submanifold only need to $f$ is immension instead of embedding. When it is immension, $f(M)$ is called as

Comment: @DanielH.Hartman, The definition mentioned by my book, It can be seen that submanifold only need to $f$ is immension instead of embedding. When it is immension, $f(M)$ is called as submanifold. By the way, Regular submanifold is used when $f$ is embedding.